# Finding and replacing commas with dots on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA and have been writing a script that does certain checks and corrections to Excel-files. I am trying to find a way to replace all commas with dots in the workbook but without success. I have tried using the Replace-method but somehow it screws up my workbook even more. I think the problem has something to do with the local settings for decimal separators.

```
Row = lRow
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Do While Row >= 2
    Range("P" & Row).Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns

    Row = Row - 1
Loop
Row = lRow

Do While Row >= 2
    Range("Q" & Row).Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Row = Row - 1
Loop
Row = lRow
```

The loop is supposed to replace all commas with dots in columns P and Q. But instead of dots dashes appear.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I have now added the code to my original post.

Comment: Maybe also clarify if it is only number formats you are trying to change or if it is actually all the "," you want as ".".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your entire shown code should boil down to:

```
Range("P1:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to change the European decimals format to US decimals format. Like 123.456,00 to 123,456.00. The settings for decimal separators may matter.

If your code doesn't work, you need to check the original value in the cells. I suggest to compare `.Value`, `.Value2` and `.Text` first.